# Azure.Storage.Blobs. Authentication error writing Metadata

Tags: azure, authentication, storage, metadata

I'm currently trying to convert from the deprecated WindowsAzure.Storage to Azure.Storage.Blobs. Testing of the conversion was going fine for a few hours then all of a sudden I started getting authentication errors when writing to the metadata. Reading and writing of the blob storage itself works OK. The authentication error only happens when writing to the metadata.

**The error details:**

```
AuthenticationFailed
Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:aff5570b-d01e-0000-2489-91c2ef000000
Time:2022-07-06T22:43:12.4693557Z
Status: 403 (Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.)
ErrorCode: AuthenticationFailed

Additional Information:
AuthenticationErrorDetail: The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'yeIjNymEfC1YSyBNl1eTm8vpHHIcTMguAQRiaApU4xs=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'PUT

x-ms-client-request-id:fbb1de4d-3163-4ba9-a73b-4434b0fdca4a
x-ms-date:Wed, 06 Jul 2022 22:43:12 GMT
x-ms-meta-testmetadata:Test Data
x-ms-return-client-request-id:true
x-ms-version:2021-06-08
/(My Storage Base)/testing-container/TestBlob.txt
comp:metadata'.

Content:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>AuthenticationFailed</Code><Message>Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
RequestId:aff5570b-d01e-0000-2489-91c2ef000000
Time:2022-07-06T22:43:12.4693557Z</Message><AuthenticationErrorDetail>The MAC signature found in the HTTP request 'yeIjNymEfC1YSyBNl1eTm8vpHHIcTMguAQRiaApU4xs=' is not the same as any computed signature. Server used following string to sign: 'PUT


x-ms-client-request-id:fbb1de4d-3163-4ba9-a73b-4434b0fdca4a
x-ms-date:Wed, 06 Jul 2022 22:43:12 GMT
x-ms-meta-testmetadata:Test Data
x-ms-return-client-request-id:true
x-ms-version:2021-06-08
/(My Storage Base)/testing-container/TestBlob.txt
comp:metadata'.</AuthenticationErrorDetail></Error>

Headers:
x-ms-request-id: aff5570b-d01e-0000-2489-91c2ef000000
x-ms-error-code: AuthenticationFailed
Content-Length: 823
Content-Type: application/xml
Date: Wed, 06 Jul 2022 22:43:12 GMT
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
```

**My metadata property code:**

```
public IDictionary<string, string> MetaData
{
    get
    {
        IDictionary<string, string> Result = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        Retry( () =>
               {
                   var Props = BlobClient.GetProperties();
                   Result = Props.Value.Metadata;
               } );

        return Result;
    }

    set
    {
        Retry( () =>
               {
                   BlobClient.SetMetadata( value );
               } );
    }
}
```

Any ideas as to why this only happens on the metadata appreciated.

Comment: What version of SDK you are using? How are you connecting to your Storage account?

Comment: The SDK version is 12.12.0 and I'm using a connection string to connect. Also in .NET 4.8

Comment: 12.13.0 was just released. Still won't write the metadata.

Comment: I just tried setting metadata on a blob in my storage account using SDK version 12.13.0 and it worked fine for me. I used .Net 6 though. Can you share your complete code?

Comment: Sorry I can't. My company wouldn't like it. Also I would have to put up the source for the whole class library and associated libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. It's because the metadata body had a new line at the end of the text. It appears the metadata body can only be single line text.

Comment: Thanks man , i just faced same issue, running on a bulk database , trailing spaces were the issue. .trim() to the rescue

Comment: Your most welcome.